# one of multiple view holders not updating

Tags: android, kotlin, chat, okhttp

I have Implemented Multiple ViewHolders in Android using Kotlin for a chat app I'm working on, the viewholders or sides are one for service provider and the other for the client, when I sent a message from the client side the UI get updated correctly with data, time and the message but when I recive a message from the provider side the UI wont get updated Unless I leave the chat activity and get back to it, note that onMessage isn't being called.Ill leave below what I should be expecting if it was working.

{"serverMessage":true,"status":"received","error":"","info":"","clientSideMessageId":"1695284902791"}
{"serverMessage":true,"status":"saved","error":"","info":"","clientSideMessageId":"1695284902791"}

I'll provide the code for the adapter and my chatActivity.

the web socket URL has been edited for privacy

Many thanks

```
class CombinedChatsAdapter(
var chatList: MutableList<ChatMessage> = mutableListOf(),
private val itemClickListener: ChatItemClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

companion object {
    private const val VIEW_TYPE_CLIENT = 1
    private const val VIEW_TYPE_PROVIDER = 2

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return when (viewType) {
        VIEW_TYPE_CLIENT -> {
            val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.me_perspective_layout, parent, false)
            ClientViewHolder(itemView)

        }

        VIEW_TYPE_PROVIDER -> {
            val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.other_perspective, parent, false)
            ProviderViewHolder(itemView)
        }

        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown view type")
    }
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val chatsItem = chatList[position]

    when (holder) {
        is ClientViewHolder -> {
            // Check if the message is sent by a citizen
            if (chatsItem.isSentByCitizen) {
                // Handle citizen message here
                holder.bindClient(chatsItem as ChatsItem)
            } else {
                // Handle provider message here (if needed)
            }
        }

        is ProviderViewHolder -> {
            // Check if the message is sent by a citizen
            if (!chatsItem.isSentByCitizen) {
                // Handle provider message here
                holder.bindProvider(chatsItem as ChatsItem)
            } else {
                // Handle citizen message here (if needed)
            }
        }
    }
}
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return chatList.size
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    val chatsItem = chatList[position]
    return if (chatsItem.isSentByCitizen) {
        VIEW_TYPE_CLIENT
    } else {
        VIEW_TYPE_PROVIDER
    }
}

inner class ClientViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val clickedChat = chatList[adapterPosition]
            if (clickedChat is ChatsItem) {
                itemClickListener.onItemClick(clickedChat)
            }
        }
    }

    fun bindClient(chatsItem: ChatsItem) {
        val (dateString, timeString) = separateDateAndTime(chatsItem)

        itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_gchat_date_me).text =
            dateString
        itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_gchat_message_me).text =
            chatsItem.text

        itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_gchat_timestamp_me).text =
            timeString
        Log.d(
            "ClientViewHolder",
            "chattime: ${chatsItem.creationTime}, text: ${chatsItem.text}, date: $dateString"
        )
    }
}
fun addMessage(item: ChatsItem) {
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
        this.chatList.add(item)
        notifyItemInserted(chatList.size - 1)
        println("==========================================")
        Log.d("CombinedChatsAdapter", "${this.chatList}")
        Log.d("CombinedChatsAdapter", "${this.chatList.size}")
        println("==========================================")
        Log.d("CombinedChatsAdapter", "Adding new message: $item")
    }
}
inner class ProviderViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val clickedChat = chatList[adapterPosition]
            if (clickedChat is ChatsItem) {
                itemClickListener.onItemClick(clickedChat)
            }
        }
    }

    fun bindProvider(chatsItem: ChatsItem) {
        val (dateString, timeString) = separateDateAndTime(chatsItem)

        itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_gchat_date_other).text = dateString
        itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_gchat_message_other).text = chatsItem.text
        itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_gchat_user_other).text =
            chatsItem.creatorUserName
        itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_gchat_timestamp_other).text = timeString

        Log.d(
            "ProviderViewHolder",
            "chattime: ${chatsItem.creationTime}, text: ${chatsItem.text}, date: $dateString"
        )
    }
}


interface ChatItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(chatsItem: ChatsItem)
}
```

}

ChatActivity

```
class ChatActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CombinedChatsAdapter.ChatItemClickListener {
private lateinit var chatRecyclerView: RecyclerView
private lateinit var adapter: CombinedChatsAdapter
private lateinit var messageEditText: EditText // Add this
private lateinit var rootView: View // Declare it at the class level
private lateinit var webSocket: WebSocket
private var NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000
private var hcIdChat: Int? = null
private var serviceIDChat: Int? = null
private var chatHcWplace: String? = null
private var chatHcSerID: Int? = null
private var chatCreatorID: Int? = null
var storedUserName: String? = null
private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
private lateinit var messageObj: MessageObject
private lateinit var newChatsItem: ChatsItem
lateinit var swipeRefreshLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout
private var chatList: MutableList<ChatMessage> = mutableListOf()
lateinit var cAda: CombinedChatsAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat)
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar)
    initWebSocket()

    rootView = window.decorView.rootView
    val slideInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in)
    val slideOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out)
    swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.container)

    chatRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_gchat)
    chatRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    val layoutManager = chatRecyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
    layoutManager.stackFromEnd = true
    adapter = CombinedChatsAdapter(mutableListOf(), this)
    chatRecyclerView.adapter = adapter


    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener {

        // on below line we are setting is refreshing to false.
        swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    storedUserName = SecurePreferencesManager.getUserName(this@ChatActivity)
    chatHcWplace = intent.getStringExtra("serviceHcW")//wplace
    chatHcSerID = intent.getIntExtra("hcServiceId", -1)
    chatCreatorID = intent.getIntExtra("creatorUserId", -1)
    hcIdChat = intent.getIntExtra("hcId", -1)
    serviceIDChat = intent.getIntExtra("serviceId", -1)

    Log.d("ChatActivity", "chatHcWplace: $chatHcWplace")
    Log.d("ChatActivity", "chatHcSerID: $chatHcSerID")
    Log.d("ChatActivity", "chatCreatorID: $chatCreatorID")
    Log.d("ChatActivity", "hcIdChat: $hcIdChat")
    Log.d("ChatActivity", "hcServiceIDChat: $serviceIDChat")//
    messageEditText = findViewById(R.id.edit_gchat_message) // Initialize the EditText here

    if (chatHcSerID != -1 && chatCreatorID != -1) {
        fetchDataForChats(chatHcWplace.toString(), chatHcSerID!!, chatCreatorID!!)
        Log.d(
            "ClickedIdAndHcWplace",
            "chatHcSerID: $chatHcSerID, hcWplace: $chatHcWplace,creatorId:$chatCreatorID"
        )
    }
    val sendButton: MaterialButton = findViewById(R.id.button_gchat_send)
    val keyboardOpenClickListener = View.OnClickListener {
        sen(chatCreatorID!!)
        val typedMessage = messageEditText.text.toString()
        messageEditText.text.clear()
    }
    val keyboardClosedClickListener = View.OnClickListener {
        // Handle the click action when the keyboard is closed
        Toast.makeText(this@ChatActivity, "Keyboard is closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    rootView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
        ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        private var isKeyboardVisible = false
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            val rect = Rect()
            rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect)
            val screenHeight = rootView.height
            val keypadHeight = screenHeight - rect.bottom

            val animateButtons = keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15

            val sendButtonIcon = if (animateButtons) {
                R.drawable.send_button_default // Set the keyboard open icon
            } else {
                R.drawable.voice_button_keyboard // Set the keyboard closed icon
            }
            sendButton.icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@ChatActivity, sendButtonIcon)

            if (animateButtons) {
                sendButton.setOnClickListener(keyboardOpenClickListener)
            } else {
                sendButton.setOnClickListener(keyboardClosedClickListener)
            }

            isKeyboardVisible = animateButtons
        }
    })
}


private fun initWebSocket() {
    val url = "wss://infoma//wss"
    val httpUrl =
        url.replaceFirst("^http:".toRegex(), "ws:").replaceFirst("^https:".toRegex(), "wss:")

    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()

    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(httpUrl)
        .build()

    val wsListener = object : WebSocketListener() {
        override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response) {
            // WebSocket connection opened
            Log.d("WebSocket", "WebSocket connection opened")
        }

        override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {
            // Received a new message via WebSocket
            runOnUiThread {
                Log.d("WebSocket", "Adding message to adapter")
                adapter.addMessage(newChatsItem)
                // Notify that the dataset has changed to reflect the new message
                adapter.notifyItemChanged(chatList.size - 1)
                // Scroll to the newly added message (last item)
                chatRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(chatList.size - 1)
            }
        }

        override fun onClosing(webSocket: WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String) {
            // WebSocket is closing
            Log.d("WebSocket", "WebSocket closing: $code / $reason")
            webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, null)
        }

        override fun onFailure(webSocket: WebSocket, t: Throwable, response: Response?) {
            // WebSocket encountered an error
            Log.e("WebSocket", "WebSocket error: ${t.message}")
        }
    }
    webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, wsListener)
}

private fun parseMessage(message: String): ChatsItem {
    // Parse the message JSON and create a ChatsItem
    val gson = Gson()
    return gson.fromJson(message, ChatsItem::class.java)
}

private fun sen(userId: Int) {

    messageObj = MessageObject(
        CreatorUserName = storedUserName!!,
        Text = messageEditText.text.toString().trim(),
        HCServiceId = chatHcSerID!!,
        HC_WPLACE = chatHcWplace!!,
        HCId = hcIdChat!!,
        CreatorUserId = chatCreatorID!!,
        MessageTypeId = 1,
        IsSentByCitizen = true,
        ServiceId = serviceIDChat!!,
        clientSideMessageId = Date().getTime().toString(),
    )
    Log.d("message", "$messageObj")

    if (messageObj != null) {
        val gson = Gson()
        val messageJson = gson.toJson(messageObj)
        webSocket.send(messageJson)
        newChatsItem = ChatsItem(
            creatorUserName = messageObj.CreatorUserName,
            text = messageObj.Text,
            hcServiceId = messageObj.HCServiceId,
            hC_WPLACE = messageObj.HC_WPLACE,
            hcId = messageObj.HCId,
            creatorUserId = messageObj.CreatorUserId,
            isSentByCitizen = messageObj.IsSentByCitizen,
            serviceId = messageObj.ServiceId,
            clientSideMessageId = messageObj.clientSideMessageId,
            MessageTypeId = 1
        )
        //
    Log.d("tag2hcCreatorUserName", "{${newChatsItem.creatorUserName}")
    Log.d("tag2hcServiceIDChat", "${newChatsItem.hcServiceId}")
    Log.d("tag2chatHcWplace", newChatsItem.hC_WPLACE)
    Log.d("tag2hcIdChat", "${newChatsItem.hcId}")
    Log.d("tag2chatCreatorID", "${newChatsItem.creatorUserId}")
    Log.d("tag2serviceId", "${newChatsItem.serviceId}")
        runOnUiThread {
            Log.d("sen", "Adding message to adapter")
            this.adapter.addMessage(newChatsItem)
            // Notify only when a new message is added
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(chatList.size - 1)
            // Scroll to the newly added message (last item)
            chatRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(chatList.size - 1)
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("tag2", "MessageObject is null")
    }
}

private fun fetchDataForChats(hcWplace: String, HCServiceId: Int, citizenId: Int) {
    val client = OkHttpClient()

    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    val storedAccessToken = SecurePreferencesManager.getAccessToken(this)
    val gson = Gson()
    val accessTokenResponse = gson.fromJson(storedAccessToken, AccessTokenResponse::class.java)
    val accessToken = accessTokenResponse.result.accessToken

    val apiUrl =
        "https://infomapapp.com/hessages?hcWplace=$hcWplace&HCServiceId=$HCServiceId&citizenId=$citizenId"

    if (accessToken.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        Log.d("response", "Access token is missing")
        return
    }
    if (hcWplace.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        Log.d("responseHcwplace", "hcWplace is missing")
        return
    }

    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(apiUrl)
        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $accessToken")
        .get()
        .build()

    Log.d("ApiRequest", "Sending API request: $request")

    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val response = client.newCall(request).execute()

            Log.d("ApiResponse", "Received API response: $response")

            if (!response.isSuccessful) {
                val responseBody = response.body?.string()
                return@launch
            }
            val responseData = response.body?.string()

            val responseJson = JSONObject(responseData)
            val itemsArray = responseJson.getJSONArray("result")

            val newChatList = gson.fromJson<List<ChatsItem>>(
                itemsArray.toString(),
                object : TypeToken<List<ChatsItem>>() {}.type
            )

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                chatList.addAll(newChatList) // Add the new data
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                Log.d("chatListFetch", "$chatList")

                cAda = CombinedChatsAdapter(
                    chatList, object : CombinedChatsAdapter.ChatItemClickListener {
                        override fun onItemClick(chatsItem: ChatsItem) {
                            // Handle click here
                        }
                    }
                )
                chatRecyclerView.adapter = cAda

                // Update the adapter reference to point to the new combinedAdapter
                adapter = cAda
                chatRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(chatList.size - 1)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                Log.e("response", "$e")
            }
        }
    }
}


private fun getErrorMessageFromResponse(responseBody: String?): String {
    return "Server returned an error"
}

override fun onItemClick(chatsItem: ChatsItem) {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}
```

}